# Add a module in other module

Tags: magento2, php, xml, phtml

good afternoon
I have the MageWorx multifee module and Id like to add the multifee on the quotes of the Cart2Quote module (emails ect). How can I do this
Thank you for the attention
Malka Hakuk

Answer (score 0):

exactly what does it mean? Do you want to add a block from multifee into Cart2Quote? You can use methods or blocks inside of other modules.